# Round float values accurately with output required decimal point in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, numbers

How to round a `float value` like `1.449567` accurately.

The output value should be **required decimal point floate value**.

**Output should be like this:**

```
for 1 decimal point  **f=1.5**
for 2 decimal point  **f=1.45**
for 3 decimal point  **f=1.450**
for 4 decimal point  **f=1.4496**
```

Comment: According to my math knowledge, 1.449 rounds to 1.4 and not to 1.5 if rounded to one decimal place...

Comment: And 1.450, and 1.4496.

Comment: What you did not make clear is whether what you care about are the number of digits AFTER the decimal point, or the total number of digits displayed (in your "for 3" line the number would be "4", regardless of the size of the float).

Comment: @H2CO3 can you tell me the logic  for your answer.. according to my math knowledge 1.449 , for 2 decimal point  round to 1.45 only..

Comment: @GR. You didn't pay attention to my comment. **To one decimal place...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into using [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368).

Example:

```
float roundedValue =1.45999f;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]];
```

Comment: i work out your answer. i thk it's working for me.. thanks for your help...

Comment: @Mr.Frank.. it's rounding  any once side only  NSNumberFormatterRoundDown or NSNumberFormatterRoundUp . How would it do this efficiently ...help me..for example the decimal  point number below 4 means no need round or decimal point  number above 5 means add 1 to previous decimal number.

How I do this efficiently with out any amount loss , because I am rounding here dollars.

Comment: Best is use that `formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven;`